# Recursively Check Files Last AccessedDate Timestamps

Tags: csv, vbscript

I have the following code that is a part of a script:

```
Quote = Chr(34)
arrExt = Array(".mdb")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
ScanFolder(objFSO.GetFolder("E:\"))

Function ScanFolder(objFolder)
   For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
      For Each strExt In arrExt
         If LCase(Right(objFile.Name, Len(strExt))) = LCase(strExt) Then
            WScript.Echo Quote & objFile.Path & Quote & "," & objFile.DateLastAccessed
            Exit For
         End If
      Next
   Next
   For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
      ScanFolder(objSubFolder)
   Next
End Function
```

It returns:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Permission denied

BTW we are using Windows Server 2003 and I AM administrator, I even tried starting the script through CMD running as Administrator. I have checked all the folders in \users\ and made sure I have full control permissions as administrator.

Comment: The error message is rather self-explanatory. Apparrently you don't have access to some subfolder of E:\. Get the path of the last output line and check permissions from there.

Comment: I think not related to the permission. Because I have created nested folders. I have ben getting same  message